# Python unable to sort list for certain values

Tags: python, sorting

The below code takes a user's input, turns it into a list and duplicates the first element if only one number is entered. If two numbers are entered and the first number is larger than the second, the values will get sorted into ascending order. My problem is, this doesn't always happen. I have tried the sort() function and it produces similar results.

Entering `56 5` will work, while entering `150 75` will fail and cause a value error and result in `Please enter a valid input:` being printed as the list did not sort.

I can't figure out what I've done wrong and why it's selective about what to sort or not.

```
import random

while 1 == 1:
    parameters = input("Enter range, 1 or two values separated by a space")
    val = parameters.split()
    if val.__len__() == 1:
        val.append(val[0])
    elif val[0] > val[1]:
        val[0], val[1] = val[1], val[0]
    try:
        a = int(val[0])
        b = int(val[1])
        delay = (random.randint(a, b)) / 1000
        print(delay)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid input:")
        pass
```

Comment: While comparing the two values, you need to convert them to int first

Comment: The problem is that when you compare the strings "15" and "2", "2" will be greater as the first character in "2" is greater than "1" in "15". This causes randint to throw an exception, as a should be < b

Comment: `if val.__len__() == 1:` should be written as `if len(val) == 1:`.

Comment: You can replace the whole block between `parameters = input(...)` and `print(delay)` with one line: `delay = random.randint(*sorted(map(int, parameters.split()))) if len(parameters.split()) > 1 else int(parameters)`. _If_ one should do it in one line is an other question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw the exception, it said `empty value for randrange`. This is because:

1. You are comparing the strings to check if number 1 is greater than number 2. That won't work the way we expect. Then, you are telling `randrange` to get an integer from a range of Integers higher value to lower value. Obviously, this is an error.

There fore, when you split the input, add this exactly below it and it should work

```
val=[int(x) for x in val]
```